# Openshift: Simplest way to create an ImageStream from a github project

Tags: openshift

I have a project which is available on github. I can actually add a new Java Enterprise app based on this project and have the ImageStream available:

```
$ oc new-app https://github.com/ocpuser/ocpdemos.git --image-stream="openshift/wildfly:latest"

$ oc get is
NAME       DOCKER REPO                          TAGS      UPDATED
javaeedemo   172.30.1.1:5000/myproject/javaeedemo
```

However, what is the simplest way to create just the ImageStream (without adding a new app)? My purpose is to add the ImageStream to the internal repository so that I can use it in Openshift Operators requiring it.
Thanks

Comment: `oc create imagestream`? Although that doesn't actually _put_ the image there...you'd still need a build config for that (Unless you're doing a `docker push` to the imagestream...then you're probably fine.

Comment: Look at `oc new-build`.